# Visual studio 2005 closes slowly

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, solution-explorer

I experience that on several different machines, with plugins, without plugins, with VB.net or c# solutions of many different sizes, **closing** the solution in **VS 2005** generally takes significantly more time than actually **building** the solution.

This has always been the case for me since I started using Visual Studio 2005, so I have learned to live with it, but I am curious:

What on earth is visual studio doing when you have actually told it to shut down? Is it significant? Is it configurable, can you turn it off?

Answer (score 1):

> What on earth is visual studio doing
>   when you have actually told it to shut
>   down?

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) from sysinternals. It maybe because of some plugins. Try resetting your Visual Studio settings (**Tools->Import and Export Settings->Reset All Settings**).

Answer (score 0):

I've found that closing all the open documents before you close the solution helps speed it up.  Or maybe it's just a perception thing, but it *seems* faster :)